# container control as a grid editor does not update values

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, gridpanel

So I have a grid with two columns, the first has just text, the second needs to have a custom control (with a checkbox and a combo box)

Check the screenie:

Here is a link to a screenie:
[image: Screenie]

The **Problem**:

When I click update to update the row. The **first column** gets updated, but the second column doesn't

I naively added a `getValue()` into my custom control but no luck!! (Note: I'm using row editing plugin)

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('MainGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    //defs for all the toolbars and buttons
    plugins: [rowEditing],
    columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'rownumberer'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    text: 'Column Titles',
                    dataIndex: 'ColumnTitle',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    sortable: false,
                    align: 'center',
                    dataIndex: 'IssueCondition',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'reportpopulation'
                    }]
});
```

The `reportpopulation` is the **custom control** here. Here is the code for it:

```
Ext.define('SelectPopulation', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    itemId: 'ctrSelectpopulation',
    alias: 'widget.reportpopulation',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    initComponent: function () {
      //code to add combo box and checkbox snipped
      ....
    },
    getValue: function () {
        //This doesn't work! 
        return "Booo";
    }
});
```

So clicking Update doesn't :

- Is there something I'm missing?
- Should I inherit from FieldBase? Can I use multiple controls and create something like the screenie with FieldBase?

Comment: the first one column is not bound to any field (dataIndex) and works, the second one in bound to IssueCondition and it doesn´t work... ummm... could you share your model (or store if there no model)

Comment: @lontivero That was just a typo while I was minimize the code I was posting here. I updated the question. Any guesses why the second column column isn't showing any data? Is it because it's a container control?

Comment: The second column is not showing any data because it doesn't know how to render the "complex" value of that field, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works, even your `getValue()` was working, the problem is that you used a custom type value on that grid column (`IssueCondition`) and did not specified any renderer for it, try something like this:

```
Ext.define('MainGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
height: 300,
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
})],
columns: [{
    xtype: 'rownumberer'
}, {
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    text: 'Column Titles',
    dataIndex: 'ColumnTitle',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    sortable: false,
    text: "Issue Condition",
    align: 'center',
    dataIndex: 'IssueCondition',
    width: 200,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'reportpopulation'
    },
    renderer: function (v, attr, rec) {
        console.info(arguments);
        return 'cb: ' + rec.data.IssueCondition.cb + ' combo: ' + rec.data.IssueCondition.combo;
    }
}],
store: Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    fields: ["ColumnTitle", "IssueCondition"],
    proxy: {
        type: "memory",
        reader: {
            type: "json"
        }
    }
})
});

Ext.define('SelectPopulation', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
itemId: 'ctrSelectpopulation',
alias: 'widget.reportpopulation',
layout: {
    type: 'hbox'
},
initComponent: function () {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: [{
            xtype: "checkbox"
        }, {
            xtype: "combobox",
            allowBlank: false,
            store: [
                [0, 'Zero'],
                [1, 'One'],
                [2, 'Two']
            ]
        }]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
getValue: function () {
    return {
        cb: this.child('checkbox').getValue(),
        combo: this.child('combobox').getValue()
    };
}
});
```

Be aware that this is just an example.

[Check the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/voidmain/ktWpQ/embedded/result/)

Hope this helps.